# How can I copy files larger than 5GB between S3 buckets using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-powershell

How can I copy files larger than 5GB between S3 buckets using PowerShell?

There are several examples of using PowerShell to copy files between AWS S3 buckets but they used the Copy-S3Object command which is [limited to files less than 5GB](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/CopyingObjectsUsingAPIs.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must first [download](http://sdk-for-net.amazonwebservices.com/latest/AWSToolsAndSDKForNet.msi) and install the [AWS Tools for Windows PowerShell](https://aws.amazon.com/powershell/).

This is based on the C# [example](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/CopyingObjctsUsingLLNetMPUapi.html) on the AWS site.

```
$AWSCredentials = Get-AWSCredentials -ProfileName YourProfileName  # use Get-AWSCredentials -ListProfiles

$sourceBucket    = " "  #source Bucket 
$targetBucket    = " " #target Bucket 
$sourceObjectKey = " " #source filename
$targetObjectKey = " " #target filename
$region="USEast1"  #region
$copyResponses = @()

$s3Config = New-Object Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Config
$s3Config.RegionEndpoint = [Amazon.RegionEndpoint]::$region


$s3client = New-Object Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Client($AWSCredentials,$s3Config) 

$initiateRequest = New-Object Amazon.S3.Model.InitiateMultipartUploadRequest
$initiateRequest.BucketName = $targetBucket 
$initiateRequest.Key = $targetObjectKey

$initResponse = $s3client.InitiateMultipartUpload($initiateRequest)
$uploadId = $initResponse.UploadId
$uploadId

$metadataRequest = New-Object Amazon.S3.Model.GetObjectMetadataRequest
$metadataRequest.BucketName = $sourceBucket
$metadataRequest.Key = $sourceObjectKey

$metadataResponse = New-Object Amazon.S3.Model.GetObjectMetadataResponse
$metadataResponse = $s3client.GetObjectMetadata($metadataRequest)
$objectSize = $metadataResponse.ContentLength; # in bytes
$objectSize

$partSize = 1GB
$objectSize / $partSize

$bytePosition = 0
for ($i = 1; $bytePosition -lt $objectSize; $i++)
{
    $copyRequest = New-Object Amazon.S3.Model.CopyPartRequest  
    $copyRequest.DestinationBucket = $targetBucket
    $copyRequest.DestinationKey = $targetObjectKey
    $copyRequest.SourceBucket = $sourceBucket
    $copyRequest.SourceKey = $sourceObjectKey
    $copyRequest.UploadId = $uploadId
    $copyRequest.FirstByte = $bytePosition
    $copyRequest.LastByte = if ($bytePosition + $partSize - 1 -ge $objectSize) { $objectSize - 1} else {$bytePosition + $partSize - 1}
    $copyRequest.PartNumber = $i

    $copyResponses += $s3Client.CopyPart($copyRequest)
    $bytePosition += $partSize                     
}

$completeRequest  =  New-Object Amazon.S3.Model.CompleteMultipartUploadRequest
$completeRequest.BucketName = $targetBucket
$completeRequest.Key = $targetObjectKey
$completeRequest.UploadId = $uploadId
$completeRequest.AddPartETags($copyResponses)

$completeUploadResponse =$s3Client.CompleteMultipartUpload($completeRequest)
```

Comment: That's awesome, thanks for translating this into PowerShell!  As an aside, Write-S3Object has been implemented such that it [handles S3 multipart upload transparently](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/items/Write-S3Object.html), hopefully Copy-S3Object will do the same someday.

Comment: If you don't want to pass in the credentials into the `AmazonS3Client`, you can make use of the ctor and pass in the region directly: `New-Object Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Client($region)`. This was key when using this approach in eu-central-1.